# Why my query does not return correct data (NORTHWIND)?

Tags: sql-server, exists

```
select * 
from orders o
WHERE EXISTS 
(
  select 1 
  from orders o2 
  where o2.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID  
    AND YEAR(o2.OrderDate) = 1997 
    and MONTH(o2.OrderDate) = 9 
    AND DAY(o2.OrderDate) = 5
)
```

I expect to receive only two records in result instead of 228. 
As you can see this is EXISTS on the same table. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two orders with an `orderdate=1997-09-05`.  One for employee=4 and one for employee=7.  Now, for employee=4, there are 156 rows on the order table and for employee=7, there are 72 rows on the order table.  That totals to 228.  Your query is returning all orders where the employeeid matches those two id's.

Alter your query to include a check for `o2.OrderDate=o.OrderDate`

```
SELECT *
FROM orders o
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM orders o2
        WHERE o2.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
            AND YEAR(o2.OrderDate) = 1997
            AND MONTH(o2.OrderDate) = 9
            AND DAY(o2.OrderDate) = 5
            AND o2.OrderDate = o.OrderDate
        )
```

---

Based on your example, you would get the same results by simplifying the query to:

```
select * from orders where orderdate = '1997-09-05'
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you are using two tables based on this code: o2.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID.

you need to use JOIN for you to be able to get the correct data.